# mui-datatables: How to display data from an AP with custom columns?

Tags: reactjs, redux, material-ui, mui-datatable

mui-datatables : How can I choose the data I want to display from my API? Basically, I don't want to display all the data that my query returns, but only some of it.

[UPDATING TO ADD CURRENT CODE]

```
export default function (state = initialState, actions) {
    switch (actions.type) {
        case types.GET_USERS:
            return {
                ...state,
                users: actions.payload.map(user => (
                    {
                        id: user.id,
                        fullName: user.owner.fullName,
                        bookingsCount: user.bookingsCount,
                        workspacesCount: user.workspacesCount,
                        status: user.status
                    }
                )),
                loading: false,
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

The current code returns undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Normally API's returns an array of objects, each one with all fields in it..
With this array you can map a new array of objects only with your desired fields, even changing their properties:

```
case 'FETCH_SOME_FIELDS' :
  return {
    ...state,
    myArray : action.payload.map(elem => ({newName1 : elem.name1, newName2 : elem.name2}))
};
```

Comment: When I try to do it, I can't get my data (users) back.



`users: actions.payload.map(user => {
                    return {
                        id: user.id,
                        fullName: user.owner.fullName,
                        booking: user.bookingsCount,
                        workspace: user.workspacesCount,
                        status: user.status,
                        createdAt: user.createdAt,
                    }
                }),`

Comment: Ok there is a thing.. fix this line:
myArray : action.payload.map(elem => ({newName1 : elem.name1, newName2 : elem.name2}))

Comment: When I try this, it doesn't return data. It returns undefined. I tried it in different ways but it always returns undefined

Comment: It looks fine so far, though you can test it with mock array.. Also you should test your dispatched action/middleware